# How do I disable clean output with --watch

Tags: javascript, testing, npm, jestjs

running a `jest --watch` , all works OK but after each run it clears the output ( ~ 3 sec delay present ).

So I'm not able to read the output of test.

How to disable this CLEAN?

Or what am i doing wrong?